# Use data attribute value as value in sass variable

Tags: javascript, json, sass, less, compass-sass

I have json adding data attributes and would like to use the value of the data attribute to control the width of elements.

My sass compiler is complaining though.

```
 <li class="lecture"  data-views="190"></li>

 $popularity: [data-views]

  .og-grid li > a,
  .og-grid li > a img
      width: $popularity
```

Comment: This question may be a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if the root question is "how does one control the display of elements based on data attributes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get DOM data attributes with SASS that way. You could use a class instead for each value, obviously if there are too many this is not ideal:

CSS Class solution:

```
.lecture[data-views='190']{
  width: 190px;
}
```

An Alternative could also be jQuery:

```
$('.lecture').each(function(i){
     $(this).width($(this).data('views'));
});
```